# How do I make a dynamic dropdown or data select and use SvelteKit form actions to pass that data to backend file and make API call

Tags: sveltekit

I am brand new front end development and SvelteKit.

I am trying to make pair of dynamic dropdowns I have a PocektBase collection named `users` that contains two fields `User` and `Asset`. First dropdown contains list of users and second one will show list of assets for the selected user.

I am using daisyUI and Tailwind CSS. This is my `+page.svelte` code.

```
<script>
    export let data;

    let selectedUser = '';
    let selectedAsset = '';

    function handleUserChange(event) {
        selectedUser = event.target.value;
        selectedAsset = ''; // Reset selected course when user changes
    }

    function handleCourseChange(event) {
        selectedAsset = event.target.value;
    }

    async function showSelection() {
        console.log('Selected User:', selectedUser);
        console.log('Selected Course:', selectedAsset);
    }
</script>

<div>
    {#if data}
        <form action="?/userSelection" method="POST">
            <select
                class="select select-accent w-full max-w-xs"
                value={selectedUser}
                on:change={handleUserChange}
            >
                <option disabled selected>Select a User</option>
                {#each data.userData as user}
                    <option name="user" value={user.user}>{user.user}</option>
                {/each}
            </select>
            {#if selectedUser !== ''}
                <select
                    class="select select-accent w-full max-w-xs"
                    value={selectedAsset}
                    on:change={handleCourseChange}
                >
                    <option disabled selected>Select a Course</option>
                    {#each data.userData.find((user) => user.user === selectedUser)?.courses || [] as course}
                        <option name="course" value={course}>{course}</option>
                    {/each}
                </select>
            {/if}
            <button type="button" on:click={showSelection}>Get Data</button>
        </form>
    {:else}
        <p>Loading...</p>
    {/if}
</div>
```

And this is my backend code that requests form data.

```js
export const actions = {
    userSelection: async ({ request }) => {
        const formData = await request.formData();
        const user = Object.fromEntries(formData);
        console.log(user);
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is console.log from front end is showing correct selection but the back end is console logging empty object.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<select>` elements need the `name` attribute for the data to be sent with the form, not the `<option>` elements.

(Also consider using the [`enhance` action](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement) to not force a full page reload.)

Comment: Hey thanks for that yes that works now! Also I changed the button type from Button to submit and now I am receiving data to the userSelection as needed. Thanks again for your help.